# Error displaying result from execute immediate in oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_tbl_user
    (tbl_name varchar2)
    IS
    sql_stat varchar2(500);
    l_count number;
    BEGIN
        --checking the presence of tablespace
        sql_stat := 'select count(*) from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name = upper('||tbl_name||')';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_stat);
        execute immediate sql_stat into l_count;
        dbms_output.put_line(l_count);
       /* IF (l_count != 0) THEN 
            dbms_output.put_line('Tablespace with '||tbl_name||' name already present');
        END IF;*/
    END;


 set serveroutput on;
 exec create_tbl_user('tbs');
```

```
Error starting at line : 18 in command -
BEGIN CREATE_TBL_USER('temp'); END;
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SAMAN.CREATE_TBL_USER", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

[Screenshot: the error i get in sqldeveloper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqelp.png)

Comment: What error?....

Comment: Why is it dynamic? You could just `select count(*) into l_count` using normal static SQL. And if it must be dynamic, why not pass `upper(tbl_name)` as a bind variable? Also the procedure name `create_tbl_user` and parameter `tbl_name` are rather confusing as they suggest it is to do with creating tables.

Comment: Please view the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification; `USING` (line 11) is what you're looking for.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_tbl_user (tbl_name VARCHAR2)
  2  IS
  3     sql_stat   VARCHAR2 (500);
  4     l_count    NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     --checking the presence of tablespace
  7     sql_stat :=
  8        'select count(*) from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name = upper(:1)';
  9     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (sql_stat);
 10
 11     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stat INTO l_count USING tbl_name;
 12
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_count);
 14
 15     IF (l_count != 0)
 16     THEN
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 18           'Tablespace with ' || tbl_name || ' name already present');
 19     END IF;
 20  END;
 21  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC create_tbl_user('temp');
select count(*) from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name = upper(:1)
1
Tablespace with temp name already present

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Error starting at line : 18 in command -
BEGIN CREATE_TBL_USER('temp'); END;
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SAMAN.CREATE_TBL_USER", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: please view the screenshot

Comment: I think the problem is 

execute immediate is not executing table dba_tablespaces

Comment: Does user (you are connected to) have access to DBA_TABLESPACES? If not, no wonder that SELECT fails. You have to execute it as a privileged user, the one that has access to DBA_ views.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to provide dba_tablespace access to a current connected user. Thank you in advance. :)